# Could not find generator refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I am trying to integrate refinerycms into an existing application. Here is my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.0.rc8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem "arel"
gem 'pdfkit'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'stomp'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl'
end

gem 'refinerycms', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
gem 'refinerycms-generators', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-generators.git'
gem 'seo_meta', :git => 'git://github.com/parndt/seo_meta.git'
# gem 'refinerycms-i18n', '~> 2.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-i18n.git'
gem 'devise', '~>1.4.0'
```

I am following this tutorial: http://refinerycms.com/guides/attaching-refinery-cms-to-an-existing-rails-application

When I get to the `rails generate refinerycms` part, I receive the following error: `Could not find generator refinerycms.`

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Env:

rvm 1.6.30
ruby 1.9.2p180
Rails 3.1.0.rc8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is to run the following command:

`rails g refinery:cms`

Comment: I wish this was in the docs, it would have saved me a lot of time.